# How to remove the first letter of a value and change a value based on the first letter

Tags: sql

I am quite new to writing SQL and am trying to find a way to change the value of text in an output if the first letter is not "E" to "TH".  Then I need the code to remove the "E" from all remaining values.

I have a stored procedure that selects the information that I need with some where statements.  This produces a list of "ChildPartNumber"such as:

```
ERES0001

RES1111

ECAP0001

CAP1111
```

I need the list to show:

```
RES0001

TH

CAP0001

TH
```

I am using a stored procedure as this is integrated into another program to allow an export to Excel.

Comment: What DBMS (database) are you using?

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I have a stored procedure_ Stored procedures are not standard SQL and each DBMS has their own syntax. You also mention _Excel_ so are you using [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `CASE` statements here

```
SELECT 

    CASE WHEN (LEFT(myColumn , 1) = 'E') 
    THEN RIGHT(myColumn , LEN(myColumn) - 1) 
    ELSE 'TH' END AS UpdatedValues

FROM myTable
```

Assuming that your database is `SQL-Server`

Comment: Thank you so much, greatly appreciated!

Comment: _Assuming that your database is `SQL-Server`_ It appears that your assumption is correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

First you check if 1st character is **E**, if **No** then you simply return **'TH'** but if it's **E**, you take the string as it is except the **1st character** (which is E)

```
select case when left(yourColumnName, 1) != 'E' then 'TH' else right(yourColumnName, len(yourColumnName) - 1) end, * from yourTableName
```

Comment: As far as I know, `left`, `right` and `LEN` are **not** standard SQL. If you know what DBMS the OP is using, please enlighten me.

Comment: Left, right and len are buil-in methods in MySQL and MSSQL.

Comment: No, LEN does not exist for MySql

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it's LENGTH in mySQL.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson well I don't have time to play here. See ya!